# Using should.js how can I test for an empty object?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, should.js

```
user1Stats.should.be.instanceof(Object);
(user1Stats).should.have.keys();
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: keys required
    at Object.Assertion.keys
```

The `instanceof(Object)` works, but I want to make sure there is no data in it.

Comment: I don't specifically use should.js, but does it support `(user1Stats).should.not.have.keys();`?

Answer (score 18):

```
user1Stats.should.be.an.Object();
user1Stats.should.be.empty();
```

or, using `.and` to chain both asserts:

```
user1Stats.should.be.an.Object().and.be.empty();
```

**P.S.** By the way, your code also looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I check for the variable not being empty by using "should" this way:

`user1Stats.should.be.empty();`